# mcafee API using python: Url open error

Tags: python, powershell

I was trying to connect to a remote McAfee ePO using Python from PowerShell and end up getting this error.

> 'mcafee.CommandInvokerError: Failed to reach the server 192.168.58.133:8443. Error/reason: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>'

Could someone help?

Comment: Could you include your code?

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mcafee
import string
import getpass
import os, sys
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

This actually solved all my troubles.